# Why are the .tiff greyscale images when uploaded on tkinter canvas getting converted into binary images?

Tags: tkinter, tkinter-canvas

I am working on developing a GUI onto which I upload greyscale .tiff images and do some processing that I require.
But whenever I load a 16-bit greyscale image [greyscale image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pILli.jpg), to the tkinter canvas, it shows up as a binary image. [binary image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6r6Dg.png)
I don't face this issue if I'm uploading the images as .jpeg or .png, since most of my data is in .tiff format, I need to find a way.

This is the code that I use to display the image on the canvas.

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk, filedialog, colorchooser
from PIL import Image, ImageTk

class Zoom(ttk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, mainframe, path):
        # Open image
        self.image = Image.open(path)
        # Create canvas and put image on it
        self.canvas = tk.Canvas(self.master, highlightthickness=0, height=720, width=1280, xscrollcommand=hbar.set, yscrollcommand=vbar.set)
        self.canvas.grid(row=1, column=0)
        self.load_button = tk.Button(self.toolsframe, text="Load Image", width = 32, height=2, command=self.load_image)
        self.load_button.grid(row=0 , column=0)
        # Show image
        self.imscale = 1.0
        self.imageid = None
        self.delta = 0.75
        # Text is used to set proper coordinates to the image.
        self.text = self.canvas.create_text(0, 0, anchor='nw', text='')
        self.show_image()
        self.canvas.configure(scrollregion=self.canvas.bbox('all'))
        self.canvas.old_coords = None

    def load_image(self):
        self.canvas.delete('line')
        # Get the path to the selected image
        self.filename = filedialog.askopenfilename(filetypes=[("Image Files", "*.jpg; *.jpeg; *.png; *.tiff; *.tif")])
        self.current_img = self.filename.split("/")[-1]
        self.mypath = os.path.split(self.filename)
        self.mypath = self.mypath[0]
        self.images = [f for f in listdir(self.mypath) if isfile(join(self.mypath, f))]
        self.index = self.images.index(self.current_img)
        self.image = Image.open(self.filename)
        self.show_image()

    def show_image(self):
        ''' Show image on the Canvas '''
        if self.imageid:
            self.canvas.delete(self.imageid)
            self.imageid = None
            self.canvas.imagetk = None  # delete previous image from the canvas
        width, height = self.image.size
        new_size = int(self.imscale * width), int(self.imscale * height)
        imagetk = ImageTk.PhotoImage(self.image.resize(new_size))
        # Use self.text object to set proper coordinates
        self.imageid = self.canvas.create_image(self.canvas.coords(self.text),
                                                anchor='nw', image=imagetk)

path = 'add path here'  #Initial image
root = tk.Tk()
app = Zoom(root, path = path)
root.geometry("1280x820")
root.mainloop()
```

Is it "ImageTk" or "canvas.create_image" that is causing the issue or is it something else?

Comment: Pillow supports tiff format and can be used to generate tkinter images.

Comment: There is no code on how to create `self.image`.  It is better to provide a [mre].

Comment: @Thingamabobs I used Pillow to read and load the images. Yet it fails.

Comment: @acw1668 I edited the provided code to as much as I thought it would be sufficient. Please let me know if you need more information.

Comment: Not sure if `tkinter` supports 16-bit greyscale. Maybe try scaling down to 8-bit.

Comment: Pillow seems cannot load 16-bit gray scale image properly. Try converting it to 8-bit gray scale using third-party tool, like ImageMagick.

Comment: @acw PIL shouldn't normally have any problems with 16-bit greyscale images.

Comment: Converting the images to 8 bit is working, but I don't want to do it, because I'm dealing with micron level defects, and I don't want to miss them as a result of reduced resolution. If there are any other GUI libraries that support 16-bit images, I'd take that.

Comment: The resolution does not change, only the color depth is changed.

Comment: @acw1668 but I'll be losing the dynamic range and there by the contrast of the image. It'll become difficult to identify small size defects from the images.

Comment: I added a way to maximise tonal range into my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try converting your 16-bit image to 8-bit:

```
from PIL import Image
import numpy as np

# Load image and make into Numpy array
im = Image.open('YOURIMAGE.TIF')
im16 = np.array(im)

# Scale down to 8-bit and convert back to PIL Image
im8 = (im16/256).astype('uint8')
im = Image.fromarray(im8)
```

---

If you are not so worried about absolute pixel brightnesses but want maximal tonal range, you can do a contrast stretch:

```
im = Image.open('YOURIMAGE.TIF')
im16 = np.array(im)

# Contrast stretch and scale down to 8-bit and convert back to PIL Image
lo = np.min(im16)
hi = np.max(im16)
im8 = (255.99*(im16-lo)/(hi-lo)).astype('uint8')
im = Image.fromarray(im8)
```

---

Other options to increase local contrast so you can see defects are *"histogram eqalusation"* and *CLAHE*, see [here](https://pyimagesearch.com/2021/02/01/opencv-histogram-equalization-and-adaptive-histogram-equalization-clahe/).

Answer (score 0):

It is found that `OpenCV` module can read the 16-bit gray scale TIFF image properly. The loaded image can then be converted to `Pillow` image:

```py
import cv2
from PIL import Image

# function to load image using OpenCV and convert to Pillow image
def read_image(path):
    img = cv2.imread(path)
    img = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
    return Image.fromarray(img)
```

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand. How do you know that? OP provided an 8-bit JPEG. And why have you converted to RGB if it's greyscale?

Comment: @MarkSetchell StackOverflow convert the uploaded image to JPEG.  You can use other tool to convert it back to 16-bit gray scale TIFF image.